# Kibana is not connecting to elasticsearch docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, docker-container

New to ELK stack + docker.

Trying to setup ELK setup locally in docker.

The command used is

```
docker network create elasticnew --driver=bridge
docker run --network=elasticnew --name elasticsearchnode -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.1
docker run --network=elasticnew --name kibana -e ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearchnode:9200 -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1
```

ElasticSeach is up and http://localhost:9200/ is giving json response.

But the kibana url (http://localhost:5601/) says "Kibana server is not ready yet" 
and the request keeps on spinning in browser.

While querying for docker container, it says,

```
CONTAINER ID:76fe82529fa9       
IMAGE:docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1                                                      
CREATED:16 minutes ago
STATUS:Up 15 minutes 
PORTS:0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp                                            
NAMES:kibana
```

> > ***Edit on findings:-***

1.Initially the command

```
docker logs kibana
```

gives empty response immediately. Later on issuing this command, taking time exponentially to reply (Did not see the logs after 5 mins too.)

2.While localhost:9200 in browser too, replicates the above behaviour. 
*(It seems something like, kibana is making the elastic search busy)*

3.Did inspect on kibana container, and it also says the status as "running". Hereby shared logs too.

```
C:\Windows\system32>docker inspect kibana
[
{
    "Id": "da312a8bfbe5e47586ac7539f124500945663a0bad61d029a72147c0ead44a52",
    "Created": "2019-02-25T18:39:43.1796454Z",
    "Path": "/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 3398,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2019-02-25T18:39:48.7600134Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:b94222148a00695eb94bcf9fe5cce02547ffd963531709de15187bf8ade13ea0",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/da312a8bfbe5e47586ac7539f124500945663a0bad61d029a72147c0ead44a52/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/da312a8bfbe5e47586ac7539f124500945663a0bad61d029a72147c0ead44a52/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/da312a8bfbe5e47586ac7539f124500945663a0bad61d029a72147c0ead44a52/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/da312a8bfbe5e47586ac7539f124500945663a0bad61d029a72147c0ead44a52/da312a8bfbe5e47586ac7539f124500945663a0bad61d029a72147c0ead44a52-json.log",
    "Name": "/kibana",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "elasticnew",
        "PortBindings": {
            "5601/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "5601"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "shareable",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            30,
            120
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DiskQuota": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": 0,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/156be4deb6525acdb0b6b32d757c5da721271aa61010fac1c3bdc89e8793d63d-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7afef12f62d8f016bd357422310f4cf3cf58f5b66b4bc03294684e970682a71f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e86e9fc46fd2c18605165003912fd99161c6826dea9650fe3f7c591a06a13529/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a7e09d4df14208f4b48adf12b155a4ba0c1fb2ce5f66e2f4c2e2f2c6f030b9e2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/aaf3b5122fcff237d0f90bfe3d6ba778c4ff036f6d00db5aa6d301083038026d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/497685f1ed275b7ad5b6ca23beb3840542abb8e5ba38ac51d9b8fb20ec007c4b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/532a837d610aaeb5c0e5b98a2dc4df1d899a46559b8e4429ff14a25b5ba60c9a/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b94ac41fbb4f0941a19161f1d3289d218de10fc36c2037d0667249caf65e049b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c9fe17bf9817837aec687bf5e14eeb1e9997ef92c4873c8cd9355d57a75aa71c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6e3558bcf051abf5cf3066775f43e81d565158e3b2a9cb817a501b47bc7679a5/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/156be4deb6525acdb0b6b32d757c5da721271aa61010fac1c3bdc89e8793d63d/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/156be4deb6525acdb0b6b32d757c5da721271aa61010fac1c3bdc89e8793d63d/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/156be4deb6525acdb0b6b32d757c5da721271aa61010fac1c3bdc89e8793d63d/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "da312a8bfbe5",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "1000",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "5601/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearchnode:9200",
            "PATH=/usr/share/kibana/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "ELASTIC_CONTAINER=true"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker"
        ],
        "ArgsEscaped": true,
        "Image": "docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.1",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "/usr/share/kibana",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "license": "Elastic License",
            "org.label-schema.build-date": "20181205",
            "org.label-schema.license": "GPLv2",
            "org.label-schema.name": "kibana",
            "org.label-schema.schema-version": "1.0",
            "org.label-schema.url": "https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana",
            "org.label-schema.vcs-url": "https://github.com/elastic/kibana-docker",
            "org.label-schema.vendor": "Elastic",
            "org.label-schema.version": "6.6.1"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "3bb18d0b036874dabdc526080d6cf25ac3e53147b7b2fd44ce77ce58b6104900",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "5601/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "5601"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/3bb18d0b0368",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "elasticnew": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": [
                    "da312a8bfbe5"
                ],
                "NetworkID": "d6e0ffb7617a1a2dd4f1a15c10f7255ed560c980ad6ccf1fb573a292d4515a9c",
                "EndpointID": "91359e830287666cf834372691e2761ea239450c832551360af5b7870546a869",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Regret for those big logs.

***PS: I am using Win 10 Enterprise, 6GB of RAM and after running the kibana and elastic search docker containers, the RAM usage was close to 70% and above.***

Could some one share some input here on

1. Why kibana fails to connect with elastic search?
2. Why elastic search too fails to respond after kibana fails to run?

Comment: I don't know what happens with your machine. But it's work fine for me... Try to publish full log from kibana container

Comment: @ozlevka: Thx for the reply. could u pls tell how to get the logs from kibana container. For me, in command prompt no logs get printed after the command gets executed. Thx.

Comment: NADAKUMAR, just run ```docker logs kibana```. Or visit https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/ to learn more

Comment: @ozlevka: Hi, Updated the question with added logs and observation after the line "Edit on findings:-". Could you advice if any. Thx

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was due to the naming of my container... Notice `--name elasticsearch` here:

```
docker run -d --name elasticsearch --net elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:7.4.0

docker run -d --name kibana --net elasticsearch -p 5601:5601 kibana:7.4.0
```

I was giving the container another name and kibana was complaining that it was not able to connect. Changed it to `elasticsearch` then waited like 1 minute for the time for kibana to create its indexes ad install plugins.

Just check kibanas' logs until it says `"Server running at http://0:5601"`

```
docker logs kibana
```

Comment: According to the question, run `"docker network create elasticsearch"` command before other commands to create a network (default driver is Bridge).

Comment: I can't tell which name is incorrect. All the elasticsearch tokens above are identical.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly the following tricks worked.

1. Removed the mobylinux vm and started the docker
2. Used 6.6.0 version of both kibana and docker

This made the kibana to respond in 5601 port in browser.

Will try to remove the mobylinux and will try for the 6.6.1 version.

Any suggesstion are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this issue, making sure the Kibana and Elasticsearch tags are the same helped me. E.g `elasticsearch:5.6.10` goes with `kibana:5.6.10`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today for some time.

I used docker tools instead of docker desktop. I started the elastic search as well as kibana with two different network names.

```
docker network create elstack

docker run -d --name elstack --net ela-p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:tag

docker network create kibana

docker run -d --name kibana --net kibana -p 5601:5601 kibana:tag
```

Docker will identify container names as IP addresses.

So I got subject line issue, later I started both containers with the same network, and the issue got resolved and both are working fine now.